# Is there any way to replicate realtime streaming from azure blob storage to to azure my sql

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, databricks

We can basically use databricks as intermediate but I'm stuck on the python script to replicate data from blob storage to azure my sql every 30 second we are using CSV file here.The script needs to store the csv's in current timestamps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready stream option for mysql in spark/databricks as it is not stream source/sink technology.

You can use in databricks writeStream `.forEach(df)` or `.forEachBatch(df)` option. This way it create temporary dataframe which you can save in place of your choice (so write to mysql).

Personally I would go for simple solution. In **Azure Data Factor**y is enough to create two datasets (can be even without it) - one mysql, one blob and use pipeline with Copy activity to transfer data.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but I think my question was not clear actually we are not streaming realtime data we are just mocking it by already stroing the log csv files and changing it to current timestamp and tranferring it to azure my sql every 30 seconds a total of ten csv files. Thanks in advance